# Solution verification of a Double Integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

This question was left as an exercise in class of multivariable calculus of my brother and I am not sure about my solution of it when he asked me the same.

> Question: Compute the integral $\displaystyle I=\iint \limits _R\frac{y}{x+1}\,dA$, $R=[0,2]\times [0,4]$.

Attempt: $dA=dx\times dy$ and I thought that $[0,2]$ is limit of $x$ and $[0,4]$ is the limit of $y$.\begin{align*}I & =\int \limits _0^2\int \limits _0^4\frac{y}{x+1}\,dy\,dx \\
& =\int \limits _0^28\frac{1}{x+1}\,dx \\
& =8\log (x+1)|_0^2 \\
& =8\log 3.
\end{align*}I was confused in what $R=[0,2]\times [0,4]$ means here and that's why I thought on asking a second opinion. Can you please confirm it to me?

> **Also, as I was looking at this question another time, I found that as $A=xy$, so $dA=d(xy)=y\,dx+x\,dy$ and so my attempt is not right. Can you please confirm it too?**

So, a new solution will be $\displaystyle \int \limits _0^2\int \limits _0^4\frac{y}{x+1}(y\,dx+x\,dy)$ but now I am getting $\displaystyle \int \limits _0^2\int \limits _0^4\frac{y^2}{x+1}\,dx+\frac{xy}{x+1}\,dy$.

Now, I am confused that in the first integral there is only $dx$ and there are $2$ limits (i.e. of both $x$ and $y$) and so is the case for second integral.

This seems to be mistake and so I think I am doing something wrong. So, can you please point it out?

Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes, for example if the region $R$ is circular instead of rectangular, no point in $R$ has both the x- and y- limits as coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following isn't a mathematically rigorous explanation, but it should help with understanding what is exactly happening here.

Note that $\mathrm{d}A$ is the area element of the rectangular region $R$. What you've now done is subdivided $R$ into small congruent rectangles with sides parallel to the sides of $R$ and side-lengths $\delta x$ and $\delta y$. Focusing on the rectangle with vertices at $(x, y), (x + \delta x, y), (x + \delta x, y + \delta y), (x, y + \delta y)$ we observe this rectangle has area $\delta A = \delta x \ \delta y$ (the side-lengths of the rectangle). As this subdivision gets finer, what you get is $\mathrm{d}A = \mathrm{d}x \ \mathrm{d}y$.

Answer (score 3):

For $a<b,\,c<d$, $[a, b]\times[c, d]$ means the $\Bbb R^2$ rectangle of vertices $(a,\,c),\,(a,\,d),\,(b,\,d),\,(b,\,c)$. In other words : $a\leq x \leq b$ and $c\leq y \leq d$.

Comment: So, my solution is correct. Right?

Comment: I have edited this question to highlight another problem. Kindly have a look at that also!